# Mule REST APIKit- My flow isn't returning a messge body

Tags: rest, mule, synchronous

**Issue solved, thanks to neildo. Here's what it took to get a response from a POST

1. RAML file must have a response body definition
2. HTTP Endpoint must be set to request-response
3. All Flows using the synchronous Processing Strategy
4. Accept and Content-Type HTTP headers set to application/json on the request
   **

The implementation of my REST Flow calls a Java API that returns a Java object. I then convert the object to a JSON document and return it to the client. My Logger step is logging the correct data, **however the client just gets a 200 OK with an empty body**.

I have set all my Flows to **synchronous** and my HTTP Endpoint to **request-response**.  What am I missing?

Thank you!
Nathan

Here is my XML file

```
<apikit:config name="IAMPerson-config" raml="IAMPerson.raml" consoleEnabled="true" consolePath="console" doc:name="Router"/>
<apikit:mapping-exception-strategy name="IAMPerson-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
    <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
        <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Resource not found&quot; }" />
    </apikit:mapping>
    ...
</apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>
<flow name="IAMPerson-main" doc:name="IAMPerson-main" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/api" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" password="admin" user="admin" contentType="application/json"/>
    <apikit:router config-ref="IAMPerson-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>
    <exception-strategy ref="IAMPerson-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
</flow>    
<flow name="post:/person:IAMPerson-config" doc:name="post:/person:IAMPerson-config" processingStrategy="synchronous">                                   
    <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="PersonDTO"/>
    <invoke name="invokeCreate" object-ref="personService" method="create" methodArguments="#[payload]"></invoke>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer sourceClass="Person" doc:name="Person Object to JSON"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
</flow>
<flow name="put:/person:IAMPerson-config" doc:name="put:/person:IAMPerson-config" processingStrategy="synchronous">           
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>                                
    <json:json-to-object-transformer doc:name="JSON to Object" returnClass="PersonDTO"/>
    <invoke name="invokeUpdate" object-ref="personService" method="update" methodArguments="#[payload]"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer sourceClass="Person" doc:name="Person Object to JSON"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
</flow>
```

Here is part of my RAML file where I define a request and response body. When I posted a message to Mule, I got this error with nothing logged to the Mule console.

null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream

```
 post:    
body:
  application/json:              
responses:
  200:
    body:
      application/json:
```

Comment: Please provide some code to see what you're doing

Comment: Hi David, no only for PUT and POST.

Comment: Isn't the response status code 204 for these two operations? If that's the case, then I think it's a feature, not a bug. With POST the location header should point to the new resource URI while with PUT, you already know the location.

Comment: I am getting a 200 status code for a successful POST and PUT. The PK of the object is generated by table. The Java(JPA) layer called in the REST implementation returns the Person (along with a collection of related objects) object with the PK. I am attempting to return that data to the client. Similar to this method call: Person p = svc.create(personDTO);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your raml file, make sure your resource method is mapping the response 200 body with application/json.  For example...

```
/person:
  post: 
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually tried that last week and I got a null pointer returned by Mule.I just updated my post.

Comment: Are you using the APIKit console or your own client to call Mule?  Maybe you are not setting the request headers "content-type: application/json" and "Accept: application/json".

Comment: Accept: application/json did the trick. I was setting the content-type but not the accept. BTW, I am using Google's free REST client since the Mule console app suddenly stopped working. When I load the web page I just see the HTML and not an actual UI that I can use. Very weird. Would you like to post your comment as an official answer so I can give you credit? I will update my post with the solution. Thank you, and to all that replied!

Comment: Nevermind, I can just give you credit with this post. Thanks again!

Comment: To fix the console, you should remove contentType="application/json" from your http:inbound-endpoint.  You don't need it because apikit will set this for you as appropriate.  And it's causing the html/js/css for console to be served with content-type=json which will cause the browser to render it wrong.

Comment: In my case, it wasn't working because I was missing the colon after application/json.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (using version 3.5.0), but with a GET request. *None* of the proposed solutions (neither items 1 through 4 at the top of the edited question, nor the checked answer) solved the problem for me.  (Most of them were already true in my case.)

What *did* work for me was adding the following at the bottom of the problematic GET flow's XML:

```
<response>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
</response>
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to do this using the visual editor (in the "Message Flow" tab). I had to do this manually in the "Configuration XML" tab instead.

*Also, inserting the above  element in the main flow (the one that invokes the APIKit Router) -- which has to be done BEFORE the `<exception-strategy>` element for some reason -- does not solve the problem. However, in this case, the response element DOES show up in the visual editor.*

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this page on SO 15 times before I realized how I'd caused this. I'd added a Transformer to do some authentication. I'd customized my `onCall` method, but left `transformMessage` as the default which sets a 200 and returns `null`.

Lo and behold, changing `return null` to `return message` made everything work again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format of response for 200 status code in your RAML file.
responses: 
      200: 
        body: 
          application/json: